# I applied to a post-doc position 8 weeks ago. Should I ask about the status?

Tags: application, postdocs

I have applied for a post-doc position. It has been 8 weeks since the application deadline has been met. Is this normal / how long does it usually take? Should I ask for an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly ask for a status update after two months, but their deadline for action may still be a few months away. You may not get back much information, though you might learn when they expect to make offers.